Tablehead repeats in next slide even if \tablelasttail{} is given - supertabular in latex beamer
I have used supertabular in latex beamer with allowframebreaks. Added the \tablehead, \tabletail and \tablelasttail. The table head is repeated in every slide. But the problem is after the last content the table head is repeating to the next slide. What to do?
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks,plain]{Literature Review}         
    \small
    \tablehead{
    \hline
    {\textbf{No}} & \textbf{Paper} & \textbf{Observations} & \textbf{Limitations}\\
    \hline}
    \tabletail{\hline}
    \tablelasttail{\hline} 
   
  \begin{supertabular}{|p{0.3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3cm}|} 
   1 & A & A & A\\
   2 & B & B & B\\
   3 & C & C & C\\
   4 & D & D & D\\
   5 & E & E & E\\
   ...
   11 & Z & Z & Z\\
  \end{supertabular}  
  
\end{frame}

For the first 11 frames it worked well but I got a twelfth frame with heading only. How to avoid this?


Please add a small, but compilable test document which contains a class and the necessary packages.

Also your columns are too wide for your frame geometry.

You could use \shrinkheight{...} make make either more or less room on the previous slide:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks,plain]{Literature Review}         
    \small
    \tablehead{
    \hline
    {\textbf{No}} & \textbf{Paper} & \textbf{Observations} & \textbf{Limitations}\\
    \hline}
    \tabletail{\hline}
    \tablelasttail{\hline} 
  \begin{supertabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3.0cm}|p{2.5cm}|} 
   1 & A & A & A\\
   2 & B & B & B\\
   3 & C & C & C\\
   4 & D & D & D\\
   5 & E & E & E\\
   6 & Z & Z & Z\\
   7 & Z & Z & Z\\
   8 & Z & Z & Z\\
   9 & Z & Z & Z\\
   10 & Z & Z & Z\\
   11 & Z & Z & Z\\
   12 & Z & Z & Z\\
   13 & Z & Z & Z\\
   14 & Z & Z & Z\\
   15 & Z & Z & Z\\
   16 & Z & Z & Z\\\shrinkheight{1cm} 
   17 & Z & Z & Z\\
   18 & Z & Z & Z\\
   19 & Z & Z & Z\\
   20 & Z & Z & Z\\
  \end{supertabular}  
  
\end{frame}


\end{document}




Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for suggesting about the column width. Applied another idea that reduce the font size to \footnotesize instead of \small since I can't reduce the width. It worked.  Adding \shrinkheight{1cm}  not worked for me. But it is useful in some other cases. Thank you once again.

Adding \shrinkheight{1cm} not worked for me because the actual data was quite large, i.e., one paper in one frame.

@JGK Adjust the value of 1cm to whatever length you need
